# Is it ok to use css contain: content to create new block formatting context?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, contains

I am using bootstrap 4.6 for my project, and happen to be in the following situation:

```
<div class="panel related d-none d-lg-block">
       ...         
</div>
```

In my css, to remove margin-collapsing I had this:

```
.related {
  display: flow-root;
}
```

This is being overriden by `.d-lg-block` class which has important styles. To override that, I would have to use `!important` in my code and modify bootstrap classes. I was just thinking, if rather changing the `display` property I use the new `contain` css property like this:

```
.related {
  contain: content;
}
```

I'm skeptic this might behave somewhat similar to `overflow: hidden`. `float` is not an option for me, as it breaks the layout.

Although, I could use `overflow: auto`, I was thinking if `contain: content` would keep `overflow: visible` like qualities as well? Or is there a way to use `contain` to create new BFC and keep overflow visible.

Comment: you may find your answer here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#contain-property

Comment: This seems like an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info). Why not show your actual situation and ask about the problem rather than the proposed solution? It could be as simple as applying margin classes to override spacing.

Comment: @isherwood yes it is that simple. But, my question is apart from those other easy solutions, how does `contain: content;` play out?